# Add Function of my MutableList doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, gson, mutablelist

So I got this piece of code but somehow the "add" function doesn't work. The "permits" list is alright and the if-case is also triggered. But the last "Log" still shows "null" for permits_modulated. Any idea?

```
val permits: List<Schueler> = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Schueler>::class.java).toList()
val permits_modulated: MutableList<Schueler>? = null
for (permit in permits) {
    Log.d("permit in permits", permit.toString() + " " + permit.vorname)
    if (permit.vorname == name) {
        permits_modulated?.add(permit)
        Log.d("permit.vorname == name", permit.toString() + " " + permit.vorname)
        Log.d("permit_modulated in if", permits_modulated.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MutableList?` is always going to be null because of this line:

```
val permits_modulated : MutableList<Schueler>? = null
```

This says "create a val (which cannot be changed) called permits_modulated, of type nullable MutableList, and set its value to null".

In order to get around this, you can declare this as having a non-null value, and dropping the nullability from the type:

```
val permits_modulated = mutableListOf<Scheduler>()
```

Or:

```
val permits_modulated: MutableList<Scheduler> = mutableListOf()
```

And then, when you add you can ignore the nullability because `permits_modulated` will always have a value that is not null:

```
 permits_modulated.add(permit)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
But why is it the case, that I've seen several tutorials declaring for example an edittext in the beginning this way and then initializing it with content in the "onCreate" Function?